# Cron elimina las sesiones de usuarios

Tags: php, sesiones, crontab

**Escenario:**

Estoy trabajando en un servidor web Xampp/Ubuntu Server, yo necesitaba que una rutina se ejecutara al menos 2 veces en un minuto(30 segundos aproximadamente).

para lograr esto levante un cron de la siguiente manera:

```
* * * * * /opt/lampp/htdocs/control/cronos/cron.sh
```

de esta manera el archivo cron se hubica en al alcance del servidor web y FTP y me permite editarlo en la medida.

este archivo cron.sh tiene el siguiente código para realizar la ejecución de un script php:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /opt/lampp/htdocs/control/cronos/
php cron.php
```

se ejecuta cada 1 min.
Una vez ejecutado el cron.php, el archivo PHP tiene el siguiente contenido:

```
<?php
$j=0;
while($j<=1){
    $url = 'http://127.0.0.1/index.php';
    $fields = array(
       'idprocess'  => 'p-gen-cronjobs',
       'idform'     => 'p-gen-cronjobs',
    );
    // build the urlencoded data
    $postvars = http_build_query($fields);
    // open connection
    $ch = curl_init();
    // set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postvars);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 2);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, true);     #Update
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_DNS_CACHE_TIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true);
    // execute post
    curl_exec($ch);
    // close connection
    curl_close($ch);
    $j++;
    sleep(25);
}
?>
```

Este código php entra en un bucle de 25 segundo, el cual ejecuta 2 request http por POST, enviando las 2 variables: `'idprocess' => 'p-gen-cronjobs','idform'   => 'p-gen-cronjobs'`; Esto ocurre correctamente.

**El problema:**

es que si hay uno o mas usuarios logueados en la misma Pagina/Plataforma luego de algún tiempo son sacados del Sistema, la forma de logueado es mediante Sessiones, no se como comprobar / ubicar el posible error lógico, he verificado que cuando el cron hace las peticiones valide al cron de manera automática como se se tratara de un usuario logueado previamente(obvio por tema de seguridad solo si la petición fue local:127.0.0.1)

Coloco este Post en esta sección de stackoverflow ya que considero que es un problema en la programación.

Comment: ¿Y si desactivas el script las sesiones no se cierran?

Comment: es correcto si desactivo el cron las sesiones dejan de cerrarce, y supongo que algo tiene que ver con el codigo que deje sonde por curl hago las peticiones pero la pregunta es cuantas de estas son necesarias para tirar abajo las sesiones y si es un comportamiento normal que pase eso, ahora digamos que cada vez que se ejecuta el cron se generan 12 peticiones POST en 1 minuto...

Comment: El servicio que intentas consumir esta en un windows?? o también en linux??

Comment: Estoy trabajando en un servidor web Xampp/Ubuntu Server y si vez uso curl para hacer peticiones locales en el servidor usando la ip 127.0.0.1

Comment: Has probado cambiar tu script en php por un script bash?.

Comment: @ali ok, no deseo llevarlo a un bash.

Comment: Existen alguna razón del porque no incluye las opciones del curl la gestión de cookie? No se si esta información le de una luz http://php.net/manual/es/function.curl-setopt.php#61395

Comment: @ale hare la implementacion pero no creo que el manejador de cookies me solucione el problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Según tu comentario, y que se cae después de 30 minutos con 12 peticiones, creo que el problema está en el número máximo de clientes del apache que es 256 por defecto. Una posible solución sería, aumentarlos a 512:

```
MaxClients 512
ServerLimit 512
```

Pero el problema seguiría siendo persistente, cuando llegue al límite de las 512 conexiones, la solución correcta sería, modificar el código, y agregar estas dos lineas para cerrar la conexión explícitamente después de conectarse con el servidor:

```
curl_setopt(CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, true);
curl_setopt(CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: close'));
```

La documentación para [CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) dice:

> **CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE**
> TRUE para forzar a la conexión que se cierre explícitamente al terminar de ser procesada.

Y por otro lado la cabecera `Connection: close` es parte de la [especificación del HTTP/1.0](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.10) que indica al servidor que la conexión no es persistente y debe ser cerrada.

Comment: Disculpa lo que acabas de agregar la primera linea estaba ya contemplada en el Sistema. la segunda estoy esperando el tiempo pertinente a ver si me elimina la session de usuario.

Comment: tambien agregue: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);`   y `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 2);`

Answer (score 0):

No entiendo muy bien tu problema, pero si crees que tu cron esta tirando el servicio puedes probarlo haciendo un bucle defido supongamos

```
 while ($j menorque 10000 ){
  ...
 }
```

y ejecutarlo manualmente si tira el servicio puede ser que esta exediendo la su capacidad, si es así puede que esté ocurriendo un problema al liberar recursos en el "curl_close($ch);"

Comment: Dejsme revisar eso.

Comment: Mira, hasta donde he cerificado creo que icieron los siguiente: instalaron ubuntu seever , luego instalaron el xampp stack, luego instalaron los paquetes adicionales del curl y php para poder ejecutar el archivo php por linea de comando.

Comment: El curl se ejecuta por la linea de comando y envia peticiones locales a 127.0.0.1, luego de 30 min haciendo 12 peticiones por minuto se caen todas las sesiones de usuarios.